# Can't set the size of a JPanel inside of a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jdialog

I am trying to create a little game of Atari GO, and i have a problem  with the interface. I have a class called `GameBoard` that extends the `JPanel` class. In the main method i create such a `GameBoard`, then I create a `JDialog`, add the `GameBoard` to it, and invoke the pack() method on the `JDialog` object. Instead of getting this : [image: My expected output]

I get this : [image: What i get]

Here is my code:

```
    package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class GameBoard extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    int boardSize;
    public GameBoard(){
        super();
    }
    public void initUi(){
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    public boolean setBoardSize(int nr) {
        //setting the dimension of the board
        this.boardSize = nr * 30;
        this.setSize(boardSize, boardSize);
        //i do some drawing next on a BufferedImage
        backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(this.boardSize, this.boardSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)backgroundImage.getGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setColor(new Color(153,102,51));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0,this.boardSize, this.boardSize);

        g2.setColor(new Color(255,255,51));
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
            g2.drawLine(0, 15 + i * 30, this.boardSize, 15 + i * 30);
            g2.drawLine(15 + i * 30, 0, 15 + i * 30, this.boardSize);

        }

        g2.setColor(new Color(255,51,102));
        g2.drawRect(2, 2, this.boardSize-4, this.boardSize-4);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        //i create here a GameBoard
        GameBoard board = new GameBoard();
        board.initUi();
        board.setBoardSize(10);

        JDialog gameDialog = new JDialog();
        gameDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameDialog.setModal(true);
        gameDialog.add(board);
        gameDialog.pack();
        gameDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I've tried using different layout managers on the JDialog component , but with no result. What should i do to get the output i want? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the panels `getPreferredSize` method and return the, well, preferred size you want.

When called, `pack` will ask the layout manager the preferred size of the content pane and ensure that the viewable area, as much as it can, meets those requirements

Ps: don't forget to dispose of the `Graphics` context from the `BufferedImage`

Answer (score 4):

Override the method `getPreferredSize()` in your class `GameBoard` like this:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(boardSize, boardSize);
}
```

And remove the `this.setSize(boardSize, boardSize);`.